# host-specific request breaks unrelated test cases

Tags: django, django-1.11, django-hosts

I have the following tests:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class TestA(TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        reverse('view1')

class TestB(TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        self.client.get('/view2/', HTTP_HOST='second.test.net')

class TestC(TestCase):
    def test_c(self):
        reverse('view1')
```

`TestA` and `TestB` run successfully, but TestC breaks with

```
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_c (dhtest.tests.test_view2.TestC)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phihag/dhtest/dhtest/tests/test_view2.py", line 14, in test_c
    reverse('view1')
  File "/home/phihag/.local/share/virtualenvs/dhtest---IwXRQ3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/phihag/.local/share/virtualenvs/dhtest---IwXRQ3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view1' not found. 'view1' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

**But when I comment out TestB, TestC works!** How do I fix this problem?

I'm using django-hosts with the following configuration:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns(
    '',
    host(
        r'second\.test\.net',
        'dhtest.secondurls',
        name='second'
    ),
    host(
        r'(\w+)',
        'dhtest.urls',
        name='default'
    ),
)
```

and fairly simple URL files:

```
# dhtest/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view1/', lambda _: HttpResponse('This is view1'), name='view1'),
]
```

```
# dhtest/secondurls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view2/', lambda _: HttpResponse('view2 on another host')),
]
```

For reference, [here is the full project](https://github.com/phihag/djanghosts-testreverse).

Comment: Just a wild guess: since both files offer `urlpattern`s, isn't the second variable preferred over the former?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, both `urlpattern`s work fine in production - multiple different URL patterns is precisely the point of `django-hosts`, after all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Django-hosts. [In its response middleware](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts/blob/ad419905b80f73c627e14188c353e62280158c19/django_hosts/middleware.py#L88), django-hosts clobbers the thread-wide urlconf to that of the request.

In production, that is not a problem, because Django [resets the urlconf to the default for every request](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b882a4bd954c8a6b1447f8fc0841a3352514c26/django/core/handlers/base.py#L122), or [the request-specific one](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b882a4bd954c8a6b1447f8fc0841a3352514c26/django/core/handlers/base.py#L167).

But during the tests, after TestB there are no more requests coming, and `reverse` (and a bunch of other URL-related functions) are using the urlconf for a different host.

To work around this, restore the urlconf after any requests to specific hosts, like this:

```
class TestB(TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        self.client.get('/view2/', HTTP_HOST='second.test.net')

    def tearDown(self):
        from django.urls.base import set_urlconf
        set_urlconf(None)
```